# Customizer - loading settings/controls/sections/panels based on a id/page id

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, theme-customizer

I am developing a theme that has a lot of theme mods, sections, panels. My issue is that the Customizer loads all of them at once and it can take awhile for it to load. Also, I would really like to load only the settings, sections needed for the page I am currently editing.

I've been looking for some filters in the `WP_Customize_Manager` but I can't find any that would modify the `sections`, `panels`, `settings`, `controls` proprieties or the methods they are used into.

At this point I am getting the page id by adding it to the Customizer url, something like `wp-admin/customize.php?url=pageurl&apageid=700`

Based on that page id I would like to register the needed sections and settings, and remove the rest.

Just an example, did this with panels, controls, sections too:

```
function test_reg( $wp_customize ) {
    $currentID = isset( $_GET['apageid'] ) ? absint( $_GET['apageid'] ) : '';

    // tmpl_ids() returns an ids array of all the pages that use a certain page template
    if( in_array( $currentID, tmpl_ids() ) {
        $custom_settings = array( 
            'custom_setting_' . $currentID, 
        );

        foreach( $custom_settings as $val ) {
            ... register the setting here.
        }

        foreach( $wp_customize->settings() as $setting ) {
            if( ! in_array( $setting->id, $custom_settings ) ) {
                $wp_customize->remove_setting( $setting->id );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'test_reg', 999 );
```

This will remove the settings, but it will not work for the previewer `customize_preview_settings`, which will output all of them.

Anyway, any idea how to do this properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most robust way to do this is to do JavaScript-based instantiation of the sections, controls, and settings dynamically in response to the URL being previewed. Since you can navigate around the site in the preview, this will ensure that the post/page-specific sections and controls will be created as you need them when you navigate around the site. This depends on the preview communicating to the controls pane parent window with the URL being previewed (and the queried post ID). Both of these are implemented in the [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) feature plugin, and more details on the message passing from the preview can be seen in [#36582](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36582).

Nevertheless, since you're probably looking for a more static PHP solution, the easiest way to ensure both the controls window and the preview window are able to see the same post ID is to not use a custom query var like `apageid` but rather to use the actual `url` parameter that is used to tell the customizer which URL to load into the preview. For example when you are on the frontend on a page or singular post and you click Customize, the `url` param will be the permalink. With that in hand, you can then read from the `url` param and pass it through `url_to_postid()` to get the post ID.

There is one other piece needed here and that is to implement *dynamic settings*. Because a setting is dynamically created in PHP based on whether or not you are on a given page, once you try updating or publishing the changeset you'll see an error message about the setting not being recognized. By implementing dynamic settings you can tell PHP how to recognize settings based on patterns in their IDs and register them just in time.

Here's a full working example plugin which adds a section for the initially-loaded loaded post and adds a checkbox control for indicating whether the post content should be made all uppercase or not: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/9e9510c7f57dfbd37eb8c0162b971aa2

You may also want to consider checking out [Resetting the Customizer to a Blank Slate](https://make.xwp.co/2016/09/11/resetting-the-customizer-to-a-blank-slate/).

Comment: Very interesting. IMHO this technique worth some more highlighting. Have some question about the code, but will ask it on the gist.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I'll reply here because comments on Gists don't trigger notifications, unfortunately. The reason why `get_queried_object_id()` cannot be used in this example is because `customize_register` triggers before the global `$wp_query` is initialized (at the `wp` action). So that is why the example does `url_to_postid()` on the `REQUEST_URI` when in the customizer preview context as opposed to the admin controls/pane context.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Scratch that. I just refactored the plugin to do late-registration of the settings so that the queried object and the previewed URL are available.

Comment: additional virtual +1 for that change ;)

Comment: Thank you for this... It really helps my case :D It would be really interesting how you're going to use post meta instead of theme mods. That would be really nice! So please try and do it when you have the time, I'll be following this page.

Comment: @WestonRuter any way of doing this for sidebars/widgets as well? I managed to register the widgets based on a page/page template with an unique id. Would like to also load only what the page is using (widget instances and the unique sidebars), Thanks.

Comment: @superwinner the customizer sections for widget sidebars should already show/hide based on whether or not there is a given `dynamic_sidebar()` call in the preview. Read more at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39087 though this may be related: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34042 I think you should open a new question to detail your use case and what you're working with.

Comment: @superwinner I've updated the gist to implement the postmeta storage backend for the settings so that the solution: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/9e9510c7f57dfbd37eb8c0162b971aa2

Comment: @WestonRuter Thank you, just what I needed! Really learning a lot from this.

Comment: @WestonRuter do you have an example of the JS instantiation of controls?  I too have a TON of settings in a plugin I'm building but loading them all takes a full 15 seconds.  My controls aren't based on a URL however, I was going to create a tab component to organize my various controls and load them in when switching the tabs

Comment: The Customize Posts plugins has lots of examples. There is also a single-file extension to that plugin that has examples: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/f8473159e48fbacbef9dcd6498155846

Comment: @WestonRuter will https://gist.github.com/westonruter/9e9510c7f57dfbd37eb8c0162b971aa2 still work with WordPress v4.9?

In the way it's updating meta, will it work with drafts...

Comment: @superwinner Yes. Customize Posts still works in 4.9 with editing posts and postmeta. This code is adapted from Customize Posts. The drafting code in 4.9 actually has been in core since 4.7 but there wasn't a UI for it yet. The Customize Snapshots plugin provided the UI, and many of the UI features from that plugin have been adapted now for 4.9. The Customize Snapshots and Customize Posts plugins have been used together for years now. But anyway, please do test with 4.9-RC to confirm.